# Does "... induces same topology" mean there is a homeomorphism between them?

Tags: general-topology

The following text is from Munkers' Topology:

[image]

Well, we can define two sets of real numbers, $I_1=(0,1)$ and $I_2=(0, \infty)$ which are homeomorphic as we can find a homeomorphism between them in standard topology. We can define $\bar{d}$ on space $I_1=(0,1)$ and $d$ on space $I_2=(0, \infty)$. But then they won't be homeomorphic anymore since there won't be a homeomorphism between those two space in metric topology since there is no bijective function between them. So how they are same topology, after all? I think the last paragraph of the proof in the text is not rigorous argument.

Comment: These spaces are still homeomorphic after changing the metric. Note that a homeomorphism does not need to preserve the specific metric of a space, but only the topology of these spaces.

Comment: @TomUltramelonman, book says they induce same topology meaning that any basis of $d$ must be a basis of $\bar{d}$ which is not correct since in $d$ we can also have a basis with 'radius' greater than $1$.

Comment: well yes, but considering an open subset for $d$, say $A$, then $A$ is the union of sets $\overline{A}_i$ which are open subsets in the metric basis for $\overline{d}$.

Comment: What do you mean, "there is no bijective function between them"? There is a simple bijection between the points of every pair of nonempty open intervals in $\mathbb R$. It doesn't matter whether or not either is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Induces the same topology" means that the topologies are **identical** collections of subsets of $X$, in other words a subset of $X$ is open with respect to the first topology if and only if it is open with respect to the second topology. This is equivalent to saying that the identity map on $X$ is a homeomorphism from one topology to the other.

**Note:** Your example of $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two different metric spaces based on two different sets. That's an entirely different context from the text you pasted into your question, namely of two different metrics on the same set $X$.

Comment: Can two typologies be same but have different bases?

Comment: @Liebe yes, that is what Munkres shows in this proof.

Answer (score 0):

The two spaces you mention are indeed homeomorphic.  In particular, we can take the following homeomorphism between them:
$$
f:(0,1) \to (0,\infty)\\
f(x) = x/(1 - x)
$$